# Can't dismiss modal view on sdk 5.0

Tags: ios, ios5

I use:

```
[controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

*controller* is a modal view controller.

Most modal view can be dismissed by this, but some can't. It said,

> attempt to dismiss modal view controller whose view does not currently appear.

why?

thanks.

Comment: it's very emergency. Anyone could help me? thanks a lot.

Comment: P.S. It works on device, but failed on simulator.